# How can I make changes to the boot options?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, bootloader

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Now when I start the computer I am presented with the new boot options where I can choose whether I want to boot into Windows or Ubuntu. I would like to keep this menu but how can I move Windows Vista to the top of the list?

Comment: Please post individual questions as separate questions. I suggest you to remove the numlock part of your question here and ask a new question for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

METHOD 1:

You can use a GUI tool called grub-customizer

and it can be installed by typing following commans

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

OR

METHOD 2:

If you have Windows in parallel than you can install a program called "Easy bcd" or "bcd editor"(both are same). A GUI version is available for this too.

Comment: Ok, I have Grub Customizer open now. What do I do with it now?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete answer?

Comment: I selected the Windows entry/line from the tab "List Configuration" and then clicked the Up button on the toolbar repeatedly until ti was on top of Ubuntu entry.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're on Linux doing these modifications...so now change the order OS(keep ur choice on top) and u can also delete the other old kernel entires(but don'. Forget to keep the latest one in list and for safety also seethe recovery mode option of that kernel too)